# eslint error cannot read property 'range' of null

Tags: node-modules, eslint

I have had the same eslint issue for days now.

Everyone on the team has the same eslintrc & installed version of eslint. Their eslint works fine, mine does not.

I have tried restarting my computer, deleting node_modules, deleting anything under my user (in home directory). Nothing works.

Issue:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint *.js* 
                                                                          1 ↵  11504  10:19:47
Cannot read property 'range' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of null
    at SourceCode.getTokenBefore (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/token-store/index.js:303:18)
    at checkSpacingBefore (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/template-curly-spacing.js:52:42)
    at TemplateElement (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/template-curly-spacing.js:117:17)
    at listeners.(anonymous function).forEach.listener (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/safe-emitter.js:47:58)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/safe-emitter.js:47:38)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:251:26)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:280:22)
    at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:294:14)
    at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (/Users/jhill/gitRepo/sponsoroo/node_modules/eslint/lib/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:608:23)
```

Details

Version:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --version  

v4.16.0
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:security/recommended"],
  "rules": {
      "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
      "no-console": "off",
      "class-methods-use-this": "off",
      "global-require": "off",
      "consistent-return": "off",
      "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}],

      /* JSX */
      "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-double"],

      /* React */
      "react/display-name": 1,
      "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
      "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
      "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
      "react/jsx-quotes": 0,
      "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
      "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
      "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
      "react/no-danger": 1,
      "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
      "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
      "react/prop-types": 1,
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
      "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
      "react/sort-comp": 1,
      "react/wrap-multilines": 0,

      /* Security */
      "security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename": 2,
      "security/detect-non-literal-regexp": 2,
      "security/detect-unsafe-regex": 2,
      "security/detect-buffer-noassert": 2,
      "security/detect-child-process": 2,
      "security/detect-disable-mustache-escape": 2,
      "security/detect-eval-with-expression": 2,
      "security/detect-no-csrf-before-method-override": 2,
      "security/detect-non-literal-require": 2,
      "security/detect-object-injection": 2,
      "security/detect-possible-timing-attacks": 1,
      "security/detect-pseudoRandomBytes": 2,
      "no-unsafe-innerhtml/no-unsafe-innerhtml": 2
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "babel",
    "react",
    "security",
    "no-unsafe-innerhtml"
  ],
  "env": {
    "jest": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": {
      "webpack": {
        "config": "./webpack.config.react.js"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if I delete "parser": "babel-eslint" from my .eslinrc, the problem/erorr goes away, but my eslint doesn't work. I am using ES6 syntax.

UPDATE:

My solution was to use yarn instead of npm. Has solved the problem for the time being.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/530

Comment: Is there an outcome from issue 530?

Comment: Looks like fixing the version of babel-eslint to 7.2.3 or 8.0.1 is a workaround.

Comment: :(. Pretty nasty. I am working on a project that does not like out-of-date modules. Some version of this tool is built into our pipeline https://github.com/Stono/hawkeye

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fix the version of `babel-eslint` to 7.2.3 or 8.0.1 by running:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint@7.2.3
```

Or:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint@8.0.1
```

Comment: I didn't use this method because my `babel-eslint` was already at 10.0.3

Answer (score 41):

These .eslintrc rules fixed the problem for me:

```
rules : {
  "template-curly-spacing" : "off",
  "indent": ["error", 2, {
    "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Nice. Just remember to delete `node_modules/.cache` before building again

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach breaks all extended rules.

Comment: The  
`"indent": ["error", 2, {
    "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral"]
  }]`
alone fixed it for me. Nice catch!
Shouldn't this crash be considered a bug in eslint?

Comment: @JaredTomaszewski There are [numerous issues](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%27Cannot+read+property+range+of+null%27) in `babel-eslint` repo regarding this problem.

Answer (score 26):

**babel-eslint** has been deprecated in favor of **@babel/eslint-parser**.
read [here](https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/07/13/the-state-of-babel-eslint)

Here are steps to upgrade from babel-eslint to @babel/eslint-parser:

1. replace babel-eslint with @babel/eslint-parser:

npm

```
npm uninstall babel-eslint babel-eslint-plugin
npm install --save-dev @babel/eslint-parser @babel/eslint-plugin
```

Yarn

```
yarn remove babel-eslint babel-eslint-plugin
yarn add --dev @babel/eslint-parser @babel/eslint-plugin
```

2. Upgrade .eslintrc.js:

> ```
> module.exports = {
>     ---  parser: "babel-eslint",
>     +++  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser"
>     plugins: [
>         ---   "babel"
>         +++   "@babel
>     ]
> };
> ```

Answer (score 15):

As [@Vasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315419/vasan) mentioned, specifically, on [issue 530, this was the comment](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/530#issuecomment-581892220) that helped me to solve the issue:

*Most likely the issue is causing of wrong parsing.*

```
import(`some_path/${variable}`) // issue exists
```

*Fix*

```
import("some_path" + variable) // issue fixed
```

Answer (score 2):

I added only two rules in .eslintrc.js file and it resolved for me.

```
rules : {
    "template-curly-spacing" : "off",
    indent : "off"
  }
```

Comment: that will cause no warning but are you sure you want to off the indent rule?

Comment: agree with @pmiranda - this just turns off the rule, doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Expanding off @SergeyP's answer above.

It's worth noting that you might need to set the `requireConfigFile` flag to `false` in your `parserOptions` if, like me, you get a `Parsing error: No Babel config file detected` error after following his instructions.

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@babel/eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    requireConfigFile: false,
  },
  // ...snip...
}
```

There is further information here in regards to this issue expanding on this.
https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel/issues/366

Answer (score 0):

This is caused most probably due to indentation in Template Literals ,so to fix it just add below in your **.eslintrc**

```
  

    "indent": ["error", 2, { 
      "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral"]

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of the below code line in React **(ESLint: 7.32.0)**.

```
const color = `rgba( ${greenValue}, ${255 - greenValue}, 0, 1)`;
```

So I changed it as below.

```
const color = 'rgba(' + greenValue + ',' + 255 - greenValue + ', 0, 1)';
```

and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

For me a warning was showing for each string literal (e.g `some text ${someVariable}`) and installing these two packages solved my problem:

```
npm i @babel/types @babel/traverse --save-dev
```